# How can I convert numpy.ndarray having type object to torch.tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to work on lstm in pytorch. It takes only tensors as the input. The data that I have is in the form of a `numpy.object_` and if I convert this to a `numpy.float`, then it can be converted to `tensor`.

I checked the data type using `print(type(array))` it gives class `'numpy.ndarray'` as output and `print(arr.dtype.type)` gives class `'numpy.object_'` as output.

Or is there any way to convert tuple directly to torch.tensor?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html check this out if it helps

Comment: @mansisinha, can you please add some sample data ?

Comment: class fullstop(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(fullstop, self).__init__()
        self.seq1=nn.LSTM(input_size=30,hidden_size=20)
        self.seq2=nn.LSTM(input_size=20,hidden_size=10)
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(20,5)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(5,1)
    def forward(self,input1,input2):
        prefix1=self.seq1(input1)
        suffix1=self.seq1(input2)
        prefix2=self.seq2(prefix1)
        suffix2=self.seq2(suffix1)
        result=torch.cat(Variable(prefix1,suffix1),1)
        r1=F.sigmoid(self.fc1(result))
        r2=self.fc2(r1)
        return r2

Comment: @AnubhavSingh the forward function here takes only tensor as the input. So when I'm giving input1 and input2 as tensor, it works fine but then for seq2, output of seq1 is taken as input. This output is coming as tuple hence it is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pytorch LSTM returns a tuple. So you get this error as your second LSTM layer `self.seq2` can not handle this tuple. So, 
change

```
prefix1=self.seq1(input1) 
suffix1=self.seq1(input2)
```

to something like this:

```
prefix1_out, prefix1_states = self.seq1(input1) 
suffix1_out, suffix1_states = self.seq1(input2)
```

and then pass prefix1_out and suffix1_out tensors to the next LSTM layers as

```
prefix2_out, prefix2_states = self.seq2(prefix1_out) 
suffix2_out, suffix2_states = self.seq2(suffix1_out)
```

And, concat prefix1_out and suffix1_out tensors like this

```
result = torch.cat([out1,out2],1)
```

Also, change

```
r1=F.sigmoid(self.fc1(result)) 
r2=self.fc2(r1)
```

to something like this:

```
out_ll = self.fc1(result)
r1 = nn.Sigmoid() 
r2 = self.fc2(r1(out_ll))
```

Comment: Welcome. I am glad I could help you.